# Problems running python-tesseract examples

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

Hello. I am new to using Tesseract, and I recently installed python-tesseract on my computer, which is running Ubuntu.

The Example 1 code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/) works fine, but when I run Example 2 with the same image (eurotext.jpg), I get the following output:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
res=1
```

why am I getting different results, and what does "res=1" mean? If I replace eurotext.jpg with another image, bike1.jpg, I get this:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
res=1
Test blob assigned to no row on pass 2
Test blob assigned to no row on pass 3
```

What does this mean? Did I make any mistakes while installing? I have the latest version of OpenCV installed. It would be awesome if you could help me, and thanks in advance.